# RxJS Marble testing: expectObservable vs toBeObservable

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-marbles, rxjs-marbles

What is the difference between:

```
expectObservable(e1.merge(e2)).toBe(expected);
```

and

```
expect(e1.merge(e2)).toBeObservable(expected);
```

syntax?

Is it matter of a testing library or just a flavor?

Answer (score 2):

Based on my usage:
toBeObservable is from third party library, jasmine-marbles

expectObservable is from build in rxjs module: TestScheduler.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the official repos use a .toBeObservable matcher.

https://github.com/synapse-wireless-labs/jasmine-marbles/blob/master/spec/integration.spec.ts

https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles

Not sure why the RxJS documentation uses expectObservable()